# dhcp discover and offer messages not appearing

Tags: wireshark, dump, dhcp, tcpdump

I'm dumping DHCP messages with wireshark and running `dhclient interface_name` to force the dhcp client reconfiguration.

The first time I run `dhclient` I get all the usual messages: discover, offer, request, ack.
From the second time on, I only get request and ack messages.

Is the machine storing/caching the content from the missing packets somewhere? If so, how do I force the whole message exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> dhclient interface_name

actually this command only renews the interface's IP; if it does not have an IP then you will see the full DHCP sequence in order to get one.

if you allways want to force the full DHCP sequence (DISCOVERY, OFFER, etc..) then try the sequence

> dhclient -r interface_name
>
> dhclient interface_name

Answer (score 2):

You can also use below commands

```
 ipconfig /release

 ipconfig /renew
```

Wireshark will see DHCP Release packet after the first one and full DHCP sequence after the second one.